# SparkJava: Get route path from request

Tags: java, spark-java

If I have a route like `foo/:id` in my SparkJava server, I want to get that route string in my handler. I can get the pathInfo as in the following:

```
Spark.get("foo/:id", (request, response) -> {
   var matchedRoute = request.pathInfo();
   System.out.println(matchedRoute);
})
```

But if I curl `localhost:8080/foo/1`, then this will print `/foo/1`, instead of `/foo/:id`.

Is it possible to get the route that SparkJava matched the request against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no inherent way to do that because the anonymous function doesn't receive the route itself as an argument. But you could add the route to the request in a 'before' part:

```
// For every route add these two lines:
String API_PATH_1 = "foo/:id";
before(API_PATH_1, (req, res) -> req.attribute("route", API_PATH_1));

get(API_PATH_1, (req, res) -> {
    String route = req.attribute("route");
    String matchedRoute = req.pathInfo();
    System.out.println("Route:         " + route);
    System.out.println("Matched Route: " + matchedRoute);
});
```

It adds a little bit of code but if you're consistent with this pattern with all your routes then in the `get()` part you can always just call `req.attribute("route")` which will give you what wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Annoying to do this for every route but at least it is possible.